# htaccess internal rewrite based on %{HTTP_HOST}

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The goal is to internally rewrite *all* requests to a document somewhere on the server when the hostname is a subdomain (*.domain.de like www.domain.de, a.domain.de)

The non-working (status 500) .htaccess condition/rule is like the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).domain\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /info\.html [L]
```

Maybe it is an infinite loop issue as requesting the "info.html" might check again the htaccess rules? (even internal rewrites?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is once you rewrite to `/info.html` you need to stop further rewrites otherwise 500 Internal server) will be caused due to infinite looping.

Have your rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^info\.html$ /info.html [L]
```

Negative condition `!^info\.html$` will stop further rewrite after it has been written once.

Comment: This works great, already posted the idea maybe a infinite loop could cause this problem but I was not able to handle and solve it.
However, two questions remain:
* Why did you change the pattern in the first line (condition) in front of `domain\.de`?
* When do I not need to write a slash in front of info.html in the second line (rule)? It is only in the latter one.

Comment: In regex dot means any character hence it needs to be escaped as `\.` and `!` is used for negation in `RewriteRule` which means execute if URI is not already `/info.html`.

Comment: Excuse me, but you altered the first line in some way the expression containing `domain.de` changed by having added `^([^.]+)` which I'd like to know the meaning of since I did not do it that way. And as for the second line, I was referring to the slash, not the backslash which is only used for the second info.html (`/info.html`), not the first one (`info.html`).

Comment: You use `.*` which means match any 0 or more characters and I used much more efficient `[^.]+` which means match until a dot is matched. Also in .htaccess URI pattern start **after** first leading slash hence it will match `info\.html$` but NOT `/info\.html$`. On RHS though it may or start with `/`